# Firefox autofill/autocomplete keeps filling new username/password form

Tags: html, firefox, autocomplete

I am trying to create a form, where an admin user can create a new user and set a password to it, but Firefox keeps filling out these form elements with the originally logged in users credentials.

This is how my html looks like:

```
<input id="account-un" class="new-user-name" type="text" placeholder="Please set a password for this account" value="" autocomplete="off">
<input id="account-psw" class="new-user-password" type="password" placeholder="Please set a password for this account" value="" autocomplete="new-password">
```

I've tried with `autocomplete="off"` on both fields, and nothing seems to do the trick. Is there any way to prevent Firefox, or/and any other browser to autofilling these kinds of forms?

I am using Firefox 63.0.3

Answer (score 0):

I've not checked but you can try this old  solution:

```
     if (document.getElementsByTagName) {

    var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName(“input”);

    for (i=0; inputElements[i]; i++) {

    if (inputElements[i].className && (inputElements[i].className.indexOf(“disableAutoComplete”) != -1)) {

    inputElements[i].setAttribute(“autocomplete”,”off”);

}

}

}
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/autocomplete-off/#comment-88998